# How to stop users to continue in golang

Tags: go, user-input

I want to prevent users if entering number Greater than 5 and less than 1

how can I do that?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main()  {

    fmt.Println("Please rate our pizza between 1 and 5")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    fmt.Println("Yourr rate is: ", input)
    convertedInput, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(input), 64)

    if convertedInput > 5 || convertedInput < 1 {
        fmt.Println("you should rate between 1 to 5")

        ####want to stop program here

    }else {
        fmt.Println(convertedInput)
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }else {
        fmt.Println("your rate is: ", convertedInput)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`return`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Return_statements) from the `main` function to stop program execution.

```
    if convertedInput > 5 || convertedInput < 1 {
        fmt.Println("you should rate between 1 to 5")
        return
    }
```

Or, if you want to return a nonzero exit code to indicate error, you can use [`os.Exit`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Exit).  this is probably appropriate for you since the program did not succeed.

```
import (
 ....
 "os"
)
...

    if convertedInput > 5 || convertedInput < 1 {
        fmt.Println("you should rate between 1 to 5")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

Finally, you could `panic` which would dump a stack trace.  That wouldn't be appropriate for this case as it's an error with user input, not a programming error you'd debug with a stack trace.  But it *will* end the program.

Maybe instead you'd prefer to ask the user repeatedly until they provide a valid answer.  For this, use a `for` loop.  This is one way:

```
func main()  {

    for {
        fmt.Println("Please rate our pizza between 1 and 5")

        input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        fmt.Println("Yourr rate is: ", input)
        convertedInput, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(input), 64)
        if convertedInput > 5 || convertedInput < 1 {
            fmt.Println("you should rate between 1 to 5")
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(convertedInput)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("your rate is: ", convertedInput)
        }
        break
    }
    
}
```

Looking back at this code in more detail,

```
input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

I recommend against ever ignoring errors.  You don't know what `input` is here.  [Try the code on the playground to see how that causes unexpected behavior.](https://go.dev/play/p/-91h6eSfWNw)

And down here:

```
    convertedInput, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(input), 64)

    if convertedInput > 5 || convertedInput < 1 {
        fmt.Println("you should rate between 1 to 5")

        ####want to stop program here

    }else {
        fmt.Println(convertedInput)
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }else {
        fmt.Println("your rate is: ", convertedInput)
    }
```

These conditions are in a funny order.  You check `convertedInput` before you check the associated `err`.  I would do it like this:

```
    if convertedInput, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(input), 64); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error converting input to Float: %s", err.Error())
    } else if convertedInput > 5 || convertedInput < 1 {
        fmt.Println("you should rate between 1 to 5")
        ## Do whatever ending / looping
    }else {
        fmt.Println("your rate is: ", convertedInput)
    }
```

That way you're only checking `convertedInput` if ParseFloat succeeded.

Finally,

Comment: What if I ask them to rate again?

Comment: Then you want a loop.  I'll add more to the answer